# Unity C# - Trying to call a method of an instance of a class defined in a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to call a function assigned to a canvas object but I can't figure out what method I should use:

```cs
ScoringSystem send;
send.AddPoints();
```

This method does not work and I get the following error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ObHost.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/ObHost.cs:39)
```

The name of the script I am calling the function from is `ObHost`.
The function is in a script called `ScoringSystem`.
The function is called `AddPoints()`.

I really don't know what to do here because I have tried other methods but they involve a game object, whereas my function is in a canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not initialize the instance `send` of the class `ScoringSystem`, so a `NullReferenceException` is raised.

And since `send` is a null reference, any call to a member or a method will fail with a `NullReferenceException`.

Declaring an variable for an instance, and initializing it are two different things, that are usually done in a single statement, with a call to a constructor (`new`) or to a static factory method.

All you have to do is initialize the variable `send`:

```cs
// Put any required or optional parameter in the constructor call
ScoringSystem send = new ScoringSystem();
```

There are some examples here with condition to the object variables:   [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-and-collection-initializer-in-c-sharp/#:~:text=In%20object%20initializer%2C%20you%20can,the%20variable%20in%20the%20assignment](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-and-collection-initializer-in-c-sharp/#:%7E:text=In%20object%20initializer%2C%20you%20can,the%20variable%20in%20the%20assignment).